# Do I have to be a registered voter of a party to attend their caucus?

Tags: united-states, election

I am interested in attending a caucus for my state (Minnesota), but I am not sure if I have to register as a member of the party whose caucus I would like to attend. I notice that the instructions for caucus location says that "Caucus registration starts at 6:30 PM", but I'm unsure as to what that actually means and if it has to do with registering for the caucus I want to attend.

So do I have to be a registered voter of a party to attend their caucus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.mprnews.org/story/2016/02/27/state-presidential-caucus-guide) from Minnesota Public Radio News covers your state's caucuses pretty thoroughly.

> **Who can go?**
>
> Typically, caucus-goers tend to be party regulars and voters passionate about a specific issue or candidate. But in Minnesota, you don't even have to be registered as a Democrat or Republican to participate in a DFL or GOP caucus. And you don't need to be registered to vote.
>
> Caucus-goers are required to: **Agree (generally) with the party's principles.** According to state law, you may only participate in a party's caucus if you generally agree what it stands for, and only if you "voted or affiliated with the party at the last state general election — or intend to vote or affiliate with the party at the next state general election."
>
> **Be eligible to vote by Election Day** — Nov. 8, 2016 ....[Details snipped]
>
> If someone challenges a person's right to participate in the caucus, the whole caucus — all the people gathered there — decides whether or not the person may participate.

Additionally, [this article](http://minnesota.cbslocal.com/2016/02/29/want-to-vote-in-the-minnesota-caucuses-heres-what-you-need-to-know/) summarizes it:

> In lieu of I.D. or voter registration cards, party officials in the GOP and DFL say caucus voters will have to sign a document upon arrival certifying that they:
>
> - Are eligible to vote in the 2016 election on Nov. 8
> - Generally agree with the party’s platform
> - Live in the precinct in which they’re caucusing

This also enables the organizers to get an accurate count of the people attending.

In other words, just show up at your chosen party's caucus location between 6:30 (start of registration, where you'd sign the above document and get counted) and 7 (start of caucus, where the actual decision making happens) and you should be fine.

Comment: To clarify, is the 6:30 start of registration unrelated to registering for the party? What exactly is that registration?

Comment: @Thunderforge - That's my understanding, as a non-Minnesotan.  I've added another source to help clarify.